# Stanford POS Tagger for singleton usage (is it thread-safe?)

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, singleton, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I want to use Stanford Tagger in a singleton design.

This object will be called from different methods and in many cases at the same time. So I have to make sure it is thread-safe. I searched the internet and [this link](https://twitter.com/stanfordnlp/status/14647234945) is the only source I could find.

Does anybody have a more reliable source indicating this?